# AWS NAT Gateway does not let EC2 connect to Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-gateway

I have a pre-existing VPC with a subnet CIDR of 172.31.80.0/20.

There is an Internet Gateway that has this VPC attached to it.

I created the following

- NAT Gateway, it has a public IP and a private IP (172.31.90.191) attached to the same VPC
- Routing Table with the same VPC and three routes:

  ```
    1) 172.31.0.0/16 target local

    2) 0.0.0.0/0 target the NAT Gateway

    3) 172.32.0.0/16 target of PCX for my other VPC were my EC2 VPN is
  ```

The NAT is associated to the subnet and the subnet is associated to the routing table.

The ACL on the VPC, Routing Table & subnet all have allow all traffic all protocols all ports 0.0.0.0/0 both in and out.

The Amazon Linux 2 EC2 has security groups to allow all traffic all protocols all ports 0.0.0.0/0 both in and out.

When it boots cloud-init assignes it a default route of 172.31.80.1.
It cannot ping 8.8.8.8 and cannot curl google.com

I truned on FlowLogs to capture all logs, and for the ENI of the EC2 the logs only show ACCEPT OK for packets going back and forth between the VPN and the EC2.

I even see ACCEPT OK for a 'dig google.com @8.8.8.8'

eni-???? 172.31.90.208 8.8.8.8 50974 53 17 6 402 1600966519 1600966524 ACCEPT OK

But I don't see a reply comming back.

Looking at the details for everything shows statuses of Avaliable and Active, all green.

What is wrong with my gateway?

Is cloud-init giving me the wrong gateway IP?

I understand that the VPC must be behind a NAT on public subnet.

As I understand it, the only difference between a public and private subnets is that a public subnet is associated to a routing table that routes 0.0.0.0/0 to an Internet exposed destination.

My routing table has 0.0.0.0/0 with a destination of the NAT and it has a public IP. Is something more needed?

Comment: Can you confirm the NAT gateway is in a subnet with public internet access available?

Comment: I think that is the clarification that I am looking for. The NAT does have a public IP address and it is in the same subnet as the EC2. What specifically should be looking for beyond that?

Comment: Its not just a public IP, the NAT needs to exist in a public subnet (a subnet with a route table which uses an internet gateway). If you have this the NAT gateway can communicate to the internet

Comment: Are you telling me that for the NAT Gateway to work, it needs the Internet Gateway? I changed the RTB to route 0.0.0.0/0 to the IGW and now the systems can curl google.com.  I do want the IGW for the webserver but now I think the NAT Gateway will only be used by the backend systems because they do not need public Internet connections comeing in.

Comment: Yes it needs the IGW to route traffic to the internet, without that its just another device in your network that cannot reach the internet.

Comment: cloud-init is still giving the EC2 a gateway IP that does not work and is not an IP of the NAT or any of the devices. I can't really call this a win unless that is working. What should it be?

Comment: The instance itself will only ever be aware of its private IP address(es). A public IP is translated at the IGW, and if using a NAT it will translate on the outbound. Double check that the IP is not the private IP of an ENI attached to the EC2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222037/discussion-between-linuxguru-and-chris-williams).

Answer (score 1):

The NAT needs to have access to the internet (it is just another resource in your network after all).

To do this ensure you place it in a public subnet (has a route table which uses an internet gateway for its `0.0.0.0/0` route).

When people use a NAT it will stay in a public subnet, with the resources that would use the NAT being located in private subnets with route tables that use the NAT as a destination.

Comment: I think that is well covered. I am working this from two sides, getting the basics in place on Console and making repeatable to be destroyed and rebuilt using Terraform.